# Azure CosmoDB - MongoDb - C# - how to increment a value inside an array of Object?

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver, azure-cosmosdb

I've this schema for my db:

```
{
    "_id" : "test_schema",
    "t" : 5,
    "p" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "207",
            "v" : 4
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "309",
            "v" : 1
        }
....
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to **$inc** the **v** value of p.id equal to "207".
I'm currently able to inc the **t** value with this code:

```
var result = collection.UpdateOneAsync(new BsonDocument("_id", "test_schema"}), new BsonDocument("$inc", new BsonDocument("t", 4)), new UpdateOptions() { IsUpsert = true }).Result;
```

but whe i try to update a value on array nothing happen(even no error!):

```
 var result = collection.UpdateOneAsync(new BsonDocument(new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "_id", "test_schema" }, { "p.id", "207" } }), new BsonDocument("$inc", new BsonDocument("p.v", 4)), new UpdateOptions() { IsUpsert = true }).Result;
```

Following MongoDB documentation i noticed that "p.v", 4 should be "p.$.v" but in cosmodb raise a not valid $ symbol exception.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Cosmos DB doesn't yet support positional operator, it is on the roadmap.  The feedback item https://feedback.azure.com/forums/599059-azure-cosmos-db-mongodb-api/suggestions/20091454-positional-array-update-via-query-support is filed to track interest in this feature. Please vote there if you need this support.